Разбор, пересчет вложенных объектов

есть объект продукта
в нем компоненты, из которых состоит продукт
компоненты представлены в виде вложенных объектов
компонент может быть простым или комплексным
для простых компонентов и комплексных (первого уровня вложенности) указано необходимое количество для создания продукта
у комплексных компонентов есть пустой объект, который должен быть заполнен в процессе разбора вложенных

let product = {
    'VOP': { complex: true, count: 51, consist: {} },
    'gem': { complex: false, count: 2 }
}


есть объект комплексных компонентов
комплексные компоненты содержат простые и комплексные (N-вложенность)
для вложенных компонентов указано количество, необходимое для создания одного компонента, в составе которого он находится

let complexRes = {
    'VOP': {
        'vrs': { complex: false, count: 3 },
        'sop': { complex: false, count: 1 },
        'CBP': { complex: true, count: 3, consist: { } }
    },
    'CBP': {
        'ab': { complex: false, count: 10 }
    }
}


Нужно сделать пересчет количества вложенных компонентов и модифицировать объект product
В резльтате должны получить такое:

product = {
    'VOP': { complex: true, count: 51, consist: {
        'vrs': { complex: false, count: 153 },
        'sop': { complex: false, count: 51 },
        'CBP': { complex: true, count: 153, consist: {
            'ab': { complex: false, count: 1530 }
        } }
      } },
    'gem': { complex: false, count: 2 }
}

Пробовал делать в таком духе, но запутался

let complexConsist = {}

for(let key in product) {
    if(product[key]['complex']){
        calc(key, product[key]);
    }
}

function calc(key, obj) {
    complexConsist[key] = JSON.parse(JSON.stringify(obj));
    for(let keyInner in complexRes[key]) {
        if(complexRes[key][keyInner]['complex']) {
            
            // дальше запутался, наговнокодил, выкладывать нет смысла видимо )
        }
    }
}

Может кто понял, что требуется и поможет дописать? )
UPD: вариант посложнее:
const complexResInit = {
  'VOP': {
    'vrs': { complex: false, count: 3 },
    'sop': { complex: false, count: 1 },
    'CBP': { complex: true, count: 3, consist: { } }
  },
  'CBP': {
    'ab': { complex: false, count: 10 }
  },
  'MM': {
    'mold': { complex: false, count: 10 },
    'VOP': { complex: true, count: 10, consist: { } }
  }
}

const productInit = {
  'VOP': { complex: true, count: 51, consist: {} },
  'gem': { complex: false, count: 2 },
  'MM': { complex: true, count: 1, consist: {} } 
}



Добавьте в ввопрос пример исходного объекта из которого вы пытаетесь собрать финальный

Так он есть. Первый блок кода.

product содержит 2 ключа, complexRes - тут нет gem. У вас в вопросе сказано, что приходит один объект и из него вы хотите получить другой, но оба объекта выше не похоже на итоговый результат.

Не так. Есть базовый обьект product, в нем gem - простой компонент, он будет в итоговом обьекте, как есть. А VOP - комплексный, который подробно расписан уже в обьекте комплексных компонентов complexRes. В составе комплексного VOP есть простые компоненты и комплексный - CBP, который тоже есть в complexRes и его так же нужно разбирать. В третем блоке кода указал, какой обьект должен получиться.

Для обхода однотипных многоуровневых объектов используют рекурсию


const complexResInit = {
  'VOP': {
    'vrs': { complex: false, count: 3 },
    'sop': { complex: false, count: 1 },
    'CBP': { complex: true, count: 3, consist: { } }
  },
  'CBP': {
    'ab': { complex: false, count: 10 }
  },
  'MM': {
    'mold': { complex: false, count: 10 },
    'VOP': { complex: true, count: 10, consist: { } }
  }
}

const productInit = {
  'VOP': { complex: true, count: 51, consist: {} },
  'gem': { complex: false, count: 2 },
  'MM': { complex: true, count: 1, consist: {} } 
}

function compareProducts(product, complexRes, multiplier = 1) {
  const res = {};
  for(let key in product) {
    res[key] = { ...product[key] };
    res[key].count *= multiplier;
    if (product[key].complex) res[key].consist = compareProducts(complexRes[key], complexRes, res[key].count)
  }
  return res;
}

const result = compareProducts(productInit, complexResInit)
console.log(result);



Для правильного составления рекурсивного обхода, надо понять, по каким признакам определять, что надо запустить рекурсию и что передавать на следующую итерацию.
В случае с вашими объектами, мы бежим по объекту продуктов и если попадается комплексный, то вызывам рекурсивно функцию и передаем уже не элемент из продуктов, а элемент из комплексных продуктов и его уже добавляем в результирующий объект
Еще пример рекурсии "на массивах":
function compareProductsArray(product, complexRes, multiplier = 1) {
  return Object.entries(product).reduce((acc, [key, val]) => {
    acc[key] = { ...val };
    acc[key].count *= multiplier;
    if (val.complex) acc[key].consist = compareProductsArray(complexRes[key], complexRes, acc[key].count);
    return acc;
  }, {});
}


Спасибо, буду пробовать )

Да, что-то подобное пытался сделать, но запутался в процессе. В Вашем ответе не хватает еще момента с пересчетом итогового количества компонентов, входящих в состав комплексного. Т.е. продукт содержит 51 VOP, для создания 1 VOP требуется 3 vrs и т.д. В итоговом обьекте, в атрибуте count для компонента vrs должно  содержаться уже пересчитанное значение 51×3=153. И так далее. В третем блоке кода в посте можно посмотреть принцип пересчета.

@Вячеслав Ну там же надо всего лишь новое значение в фукнцию добавить(множитель) и множить count на него в каждой итерации

Ну походу ) до клавиатуры не добрался еще ) спасибо

Да, теперь работает в точности, как требовалось, спасибо! ) Единственное, в процессе изменяется исходный объект productInit и потребность в объекте res отпадает. Наверное, тут нужно клонировать все же: res[key] = product[key];

Ага. Еще и complexResInit модифицирует по итогу. Каким образом только, не понял.

Без клонирования тут не обойтись, так понял, иначе модифицирует исходные объекты productInit и complexResInit (как его, вообще не понял... вроде бы в compareProducts никаких манипуляций с complexResInit не происходит, но по итогу он тоже изменяется).
И еще вопрос, если добавить в complexResInit еще один комплексный компонент, в составе которого так же будет VOP, то как посчитать общее количество вложенных компонентов?

Добавил в пост пример, из коммента выше вряд ли понятно было, что требуется.
UPD: вариант посложнее: ...

Комплексный компонент VOP первого уровня, к примеру, нужно мержить с VOP второго уровня, который входит в состав компонента MM ) Ну и на первом уровне VOP - общее количество для изделия (с пересчетом всех внутренних), а на втором уровне только для MM ) Чтобы по итогу можно было получить ответ на вопросы: сколько нужно VOP для создания компонента MM? А сколько нужно всего VOP, для изделия в целом? ) Или: сколько нужно CBP, который входит в состав VOP,  для создания MM или всего изделия в целом. Дальше хотел навешивать еще функционал типа подсчета недостающих компонентов, исходя из наличия )

@Вячеслав Из-за вашего UPD пришлось поменять аж по 1 строчке кода в каждом примере. Странно, что вы это не сделали самостоятельно. По остальным вопросам, "как" создайте отдельный вопрос так же с примерами, что делаете, что не получается, что ожидается(и зачем).

Концепция дается проще, чем реализация )) Пока думаю как, Вы уже выкатываете готовое решение )) Спасибо )

@Вячеслав Спасибо - галочка на ответе "Принять вопрос". Большое спасибо + голос.

Теперь из productInit выстаскивает из компонента MM consist VOP )

Прожал галочку и кнопку вверх ) это + голос же? )

По ходу просто приходят мысли, докидываю условия ) Сорри, такой вот я программист )

Не очень понимаю, что там где выскакивает и куда. Но тут уже и так переписка разраслась и из 1 вопроса кучка поправилась. Поковыряйтесь далее сами с кодом и вашими хотелками, как раз подразберетесь(надеюсь), что и как в коде работает и почему. Ну а что то не сможете решить, приходите с новыми вопросам

Да, ничего не вытягивает, не так посмотрел ) Да, все решено, спасибо!

Создал новую тему, правда там половина практически дубль получился этой, с небольшим дополнением ) надеюсь не заминусуют )
https://ru.stackoverflow.com/questions/1581510/%d0%9f%d0%b5%d1%80%d0%b5%d0%bd%d0%be%d1%81-%d0%bf%d0%be%d0%bb%d1%83%d1%87%d0%b5%d0%bd%d0%bd%d1%8b%d1%85-%d0%b7%d0%bd%d0%b0%d1%87%d0%b5%d0%bd%d0%b8%d0%b9-%d0%bf%d0%be%d1%81%d0%bb%d0%b5-%d1%80%d0%b0%d0%b7%d0%b1%d0%be%d1%80%d0%b0-%d0%be%d0%b1%d1%8a%d0%b5%d0%ba%d1%82%d0%b0
